# OOP Solution for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, programming-languages

Is there any super set or language similar to javascript that provides a more classical c++/java/c#-like OO System. But can be used with HTML-5 and DOM and has a cross-platform implementation?

Comment: CoffeeScript? That obviously gets compiled to JS.

Comment: How about you stop being lazy and learn a new programming paradigm instead. JS is prototype-based OO language, not class-based. It's a disgrace for a programmer to ask *"can i make language X be like language Y, please?"*.

Comment: @tereško _sigh_. I was just looking to make a small HTML-5 canvas demo. Guess there's no short cut to it. I'll have to spend the 2 days learning prototype-based OOP to make a 15-min demo. :(

Comment: @IntermediateHacker [spend 30 minutes reading the article](http://killdream.github.com/blog/2011/10/understanding-javascript-oop/) then write the demo. Or screw OO and write the demo in a functional/procedural style

Comment: @Raynos woah, thanks! Add the link to the article to your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called JavaScript. There are some good [articles about OOP around](http://killdream.github.com/blog/2011/10/understanding-javascript-oop/)

```
var Parent = {
  method: function () {
    ...
  }
}

var Child = Object.create(Parent, {
  childMethod: { value: function () {
    ...
  } }
})
```

Any attempt to emulate a class system in JavaScript is a waste of time and ends up writing bloated / unreadable / unmaintainable code.

If the above is too ugly, consider using an [extend function](https://gist.github.com/1441105)

Answer (score 4):

You could give [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) a try.

It compiles to JavaScript so it's indeed cross-platform.

As far as scripting is concerned, it is also compatible with using HTML5 tags but it's not really an issue: HTML is the markup language, JavaScript (or CoffeeScript) is the scripting language. So you can still select or edit (HTML5) elements using CoffeeScript; the script will be compiled to JavaScript and it'll still work.

Comment: It should be noted that CoffeeScript has a set of series problems with it and one needs to make an educated decision about whether it's worth using

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestion to learn CoffeeScript above, you could try out a couple of javascript patterns.

I was recently watching a pluralsight screencast (structuring javascript code) and I was made aware of a couple of javascript patterns but i really like the "Revealing Prototype Pattern".

Very concise and simple, you get some of the benefits of OOP including encapsulation et al.

Pluralsight offers a free 10 days trial period so i guess you can easily get up to speed with it.

Comment: A "Revealing prototype pattern" is likely to be bad for performance

Comment: @Raynos i don't know for sure but the instructor specifically said that the pattern is efficient performance wise. And i've just tried out a few simple stuff so i can't claim anything.

Comment: if it includes creating closures inside a constructor function then he lied about performance efficiency

Comment: @Raynos your example above shows the "Module Pattern" which assigns an object literal to a variable. Are you saying this is better? i'm curious :)

Comment: The less functions you create the more performant your code is. My example doesn't use the "Module pattern" what it uses are called "objects". [cost of privacy](http://blog.jcoglan.com/2012/01/19/the-cost-of-privacy/), [privates are slow](http://w3net.eu/code/privateMembers/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options. The ones that spring to my mind are:

- [Simple JavaScript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)
- [YUI extend](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yui/yui-extend.html)